# Figures. Extra Challenge

Tags: java, compare, equality, figure

Please help to create a method like `public boolean isTheSame(Figure figure){}`
Description: Please, make Triangle, Quadrilateral, Circle classes extend Figure abstract class.

Implement methods in Triangle, Quadrilateral, Circle:

Constructors with following parameters:

- Triangle – three vertices (points) as parameters.
- Quadrilateral – four vertices (points) as parameters.
- Circle – point of the center and double value of the radius.

Ensure figures are not degenerative.
All of them must have non-zero area.
Quadrilateral is also must be convex.
If a figure is not good, throw an IllegalArgumentException.
Note: A non-degenerative convex quadrilateral is divided into four non-degenerative triangles by its diagonals.
Note: double calculations are not completely accurate, use error delta, where applies.
public Point centroid() Return the centroid of the figure.
Centroid refers to center of mass of the plain figure, not the baricenter.
In other words it should be "area centroid".

```java
public boolean isTheSame(Figure figure)
```

Two figures are considered to be the same only:
if they have the same type
and if they coincide (e.g. have same vertices)

Note: order of the vertices have not to be the same.
Note: double calculations are not completely accurate, use error delta, where applies.
Note for curious: it is almost like equals() but it is not. Method equals requires consistent behavior alongside hashCode() and it is quite complicated to establish in terms of approximate equality like in this exercise.

Point class is already there.

```java
class Point {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    public Point(final double x, final double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (! (o instanceof Point)) return false;
        Point point = (Point) o;
        return Double.compare(point.x, x) == 0 && Double.compare(point.y, y) == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
}`
```

```java
abstract class Figure {

    public double distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return Math.sqrt(StrictMath.pow(p2.getX() - p1.getX(), 2) + StrictMath.pow(p2.getY() - p1.getY(), 2));
    }

    public abstract Point centroid();

    public abstract boolean isTheSame(Figure figure);

    public boolean isDegenerativeTriangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
        if (a == null || b == null || c == null) return true;
        if (a.getX() == a.getY() && b.getX() == b.getY() && c.getX() == c.getY()) return true;

        double d1 = distance(a, b);
        double d2 = distance(b, c);
        double d3 = distance(c, a);

        if ((d2 + d3) <= d1) return true;
        if ((d3 + d1) <= d2) return true;
        return (d1 + d2) <= d3;
    }

}
```

```java
class Segment {

    Point start;
    Point end;

    public Segment(Point start, Point end) {
        if(Objects.isNull(start) || Objects.isNull(end) || start.equals(end))
            throw new RuntimeException();
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    Point intersection(Segment another) {
        double S1 = (end.getY() - start.getY()) / (end.getX() - start.getX());
        double S2 = (another.end.getY() - another.start.getY()) / (another.end.getX() - another.start.getX());
        if (S1 == S2) return null;

        double b1 = (start.getY() * end.getX() - end.getY() * start.getX()) / (end.getX() - start.getX());
        double b2 = (another.start.getY() * another.end.getX() - another.end.getY() * another.start.getX()) /
                (another.end.getX() - another.start.getX());

        double x = (b2 - b1) / (S1 - S2);
        double y = (S1 * b2 - S2 * b1) / (S1 - S2);

        if ((x > start.getX() && x > end.getX()) || (x > another.start.getX() && x > another.end.getX()) ||
                (x < start.getX() && x < end.getX()) || (x < another.start.getX() && x <  another.end.getX()) ||
                (y > start.getY() && y > end.getY()) || (y > another.start.getY() && y > another.end.getY()) ||
                (y < start.getY() && y < end.getY()) || (y < another.start.getY() && y < another.end.getY()))
            return null;

        return new Point(x, y);

    }
}
```

I tried to compare using the `equals()` and `compare()` method, but nothing works.

```java
class Quadrilateral extends Figure {
    public static final double DELTA = 0.0001;
    Point a, b, c, d;
    Point[] points;


    public Quadrilateral(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d) {
        points = new Point[]{a, b, c, d};
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;

        if (a == null || b == null || c == null || d == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        if (isDegenerativeTriangle(a, b, c)
                || isDegenerativeTriangle(b, c, d)
                || isDegenerativeTriangle(c, d, a)
                || isDegenerativeTriangle(d, a, b)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();


        if (! isConvex()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    }

    @Override
    public Point centroid() {
        Point center1 = centroidTriangle(a, b, c);
        Point center2 = centroidTriangle(a, c, d);
        Point center3 = centroidTriangle(a, d, b);
        Point center4 = centroidTriangle(b, d, c);
        return new Segment(center1, center2)
                .intersection(new Segment(center3, center4));
    }

    private Point centroidTriangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
        double x = (a.getX() + b.getX() + c.getX()) / 3;
        double y = (a.getY() + b.getY() + c.getY()) / 3;

        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTheSame(Figure figure) {
        if (this == figure) return true;
        if ((figure instanceof Quadrilateral)) return true;
        figure = new Quadrilateral(a, b, c, d);

        Quadrilateral that = (Quadrilateral) figure;
        return Objects.equals(a, that.a) && Objects.equals(b, that.b) && Objects.equals(c, that.c) && Objects.equals(d, that.d);
    }

        public boolean isConvex() {
        boolean isNegative = false;
        boolean isPositive = false;
        int num_points = points.length;
        int B, C;
        for (int A = 0; A < num_points; A++) {
            B = (A + 1) % num_points;
            C = (B + 1) % num_points;

            double product =
                    prodLength(
                            points[A].getX(), points[A].getY(),
                            points[B].getX(), points[B].getY(),
                            points[C].getX(), points[C].getY());
            if (product < 0) {
                isNegative = true;
            } else if (product > 0) {
                isPositive = true;
            }
            if (isNegative && isPositive) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

        public double prodLength(double aX, double aY, double bX, double bY, double cX, double cY) {
        double baX = aX - bX;
        double baY = aY - bY;
        double bcX = cX - bX;
        double bcY = cY - bY;

        return (baX * bcY - baY * bcX);
    }
}
```

I need to complete this method. I've tried everything I know, but unfortunately nothing works. This is one test that I cannot complete, the rest of the tests pass successfully

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

```java
   @Override
   public boolean isTheSame(Figure figure) {
   if (this == figure) return true;
   if ((figure instanceof Quadrilateral)) return true;
   figure = new Quadrilateral(a, b, c, d);

   Quadrilateral that = (Quadrilateral) figure;
   return Objects.equals(a, that.a) && Objects.equals(b, that.b) && Objects.equals(c, that.c) && Objects.equals(d, that.d);
}
```

## Test

[image: Test run where "testTheSame" is failing]

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean isTheSame(Figure figure) {
    if(figure.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
    Quadrilateral quadrilateral = (Quadrilateral) figure;
    Point[] thisVertices = {a, b, c, d};
    Point[] otherVertices = {quadrilateral.a, quadrilateral.b, quadrilateral.c, quadrilateral.d};

    int isMatched = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i< thisVertices.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < otherVertices.length; j++){
            if (thisVertices[i].equals(otherVertices[j])){
                isMatched++;
            }
        }
    }

    return isMatched == 4;
}
```

also you need to modify the Point class

```
 @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Point point = (Point) o;
    double ERROR_DELTA = 0.000001d;
    return Math.abs(x - point.x) < ERROR_DELTA && Math.abs(y - point.y) < ERROR_DELTA;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean isTheSame(Figure figure) {
    if (this == figure) return true;
    if (!(figure instanceof Quadrilateral)) return false;

    Quadrilateral that = (Quadrilateral) figure;
    List<Point> thisPoints = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d);
    List<Point> thatPoints = Arrays.asList(that.a, that.b, that.c, that.d);

    for (Point thisPoint : thisPoints) {
        boolean foundEquivalent = false;
        for (Point thatPoint : thatPoints) {
            if (arePointsEquivalent(thisPoint, thatPoint)) {
                foundEquivalent = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!foundEquivalent) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean arePointsEquivalent(Point p1, Point p2) {
    double tolerance = 1e-9;
    return Math.abs(p1.getX() - p2.getX()) < tolerance && Math.abs(p1.getY() - p2.getY()) < tolerance;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).